# Need help when autohiding a tabBar in Qt with C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt programming in C++. I am using Visual Studio 2019 as editor. I made two buttons (b1 and b2) and a tab widgets. They are visible properly in the UI as shown in the following Fig.

[image]

**What I want?** I want to auto hide the tab area.

**What I did?** This is the code that contains the widgets (tab and buttons).

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "tabbar.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TabBar w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

tabbar.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_tabbar.h"
#include<qtabbar.h>
#include<qpushbutton.h>
#include<qgridlayout.h>
#include<qdebug.h>

class TabBar : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TabBar();
};
```

tabbar.cpp

```cpp
#include "tabbar.h"
TabBar::TabBar()
{
    QPushButton* b1 = new QPushButton("b1");
    QPushButton* b2 = new QPushButton("b2");
    QTabBar* tabBar = new QTabBar;
    tabBar->addTab("Tab 1");
    tabBar->addTab("Tab 2");
    tabBar->setTabText(0, "Hello tab 1");
    tabBar->setTabText(1, "Hello tab 2");
    QString str;
    str = tabBar->tabText(1);
    qDebug() << str;
    tabBar->setTabToolTip(0, "ToolTip for tab 1");
    tabBar->setTabToolTip(1, "ToolTip for tab 2");

    tabBar->autoHide();

    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout;

    layout->addWidget(b1, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget(b2, 0, 1);
    layout->addWidget(tabBar, 0, 2);

    QWidget* wid = new QWidget;
    wid->setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(wid);
}
```

**The main problem:** Even though I call the function `autoHide()` through `tabBar()` function the tab are is not hidden. Did I miss something?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#autoHide-prop): `"If true, the tab bar is automatically hidden when it contains less than 2 tabs"`.  Your `QTabBar` has two tabs and will not, therefore, be hidden.  Right?  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @G.M. and OP is calling the getter... for setting the autohide property she should call the "setAutoHide(true)" ...

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ My bad -- I misread the code.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

the method you are using is actually the "getter" of the property, you need to call the setter **setAutoHide(bool hide)**, furthermore you should read the doc:

> autoHide : bool
> If true, the tab bar is automatically hidden when it contains less than 2 tabs.

so with 2 tabs nothing is going to happen

Comment: actually, i wanted an action such that, when the mouse cursor reaches the right edge of the qt window it should unhide the tabBar. So how to "hide" and "unhide" the tabBar?